# Kubernetes nginx ingress route creation failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io"

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, argocd

I'm attempting to add a path based ingress route to the "ingress-nginx" namespace where my ingress nginx resources also live using Argo CD. I have my own wildcard certificate assigned to `test-cert` kubernetes secret using external secrets operator.

I receive the following error from Argo CD's sync process and I'm not sure why:

```
Failed sync attempt to 0034cc49bc4151a4e07998e390edbc548037ec91: one or more objects failed to apply, reason: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "validate.nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://ingress-nginx-controller-admission.ingress-nginx.svc:443/networking/v1/ingresses?timeout=10s": EOF (retried 5 times).
```

The ingress resource in Argo

[image]

My `ingress.yaml` configuration

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: argocd-server-ingress
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: tools.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /argocd
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: argocd-server
                port:
                  name: https
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - tools.example.com
      secretName: test-cert
```

Ingress nginx helm sub chart deployed to `ingress-nginx` namespace:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: nginx
type: application
version: 0.0.1
appVersion: "1.0"
dependencies:
  - name: ingress-nginx
    repository: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
    version: 4.8.3
```

helm sub chart values file:

```
ingress-nginx:
  controller:
    config:
      enable-modsecurity: true
      enable-owasp-modsecurity-crs: true
      modsecurity-snippet: |-
        SecRuleEngine On
        SecRequestBodyAccess On
        SecAuditLog /dev/stdout
        SecAuditLogFormat JSON
        SecAuditEngine RelevantOnly
    publishService:
      enabled: false
    service:
      annotations:
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path: "/healthz"
```